# How to represent object keys replacement in Typescript definition?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Currently I have the following `types`:

```
type PossibleKeys = number | string | symbol;
type ValueOf<T extends object> = T[keyof T]; 
type ReplaceKeys<T extends Record<PossibleKeys, any>, U extends Partial<Record<keyof T, PossibleKeys>>> = 
  Omit<T, keyof U> & { [P in ValueOf<U>]: T[keyof U] };
```

...but, although it works even partially, it gives the following error:

> Type 'U[keyof U]' is not assignable to type 'string | number |
>   symbol'.

---

[**A simple demo**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=14&pln=2&pc=45#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGkIgVAXigDsBXAW1QgCcoAfKBYa5Ygc3sZErnQG4AUKEhQAagEN0pCAHkAZgB4AKlAgAPYBGIATfHFQArCAGNgAPkJQlAbQDWuOHKsBdQcOgyAbjQDuLTTh4yqoaWrpQAEomcNTaCvBIaJiBCAA0UOLEIGbpAKohmjr4MOLUwMiSClHGMXH2II5W6QkoGNi4CGZdhAJQfVAy5MjAyun1jbkWAGRQAN5Q1jBQrGKS0vIKk84AXFZ2Dk65zlAAvoICrJrUcuLG0ACSmuRzvf3UEOLacMToIFDaEAQxhYYHK312TBY7EE-Sg70%2031%20y20EOYrDYghOAguxCuNzuUAAsiB7riaPjoLNXn14V8fn9kCjGGjodS4R86UiwNQ4GAlHAomB0LcILsyJQaDC3hzEX9MnBgAALGgwHl8gUQIUi3a02VQR4QcjWVwCLECAD05qgAAkaA8AOTPdSQUzoubI1FQjFQYAKyRiihUah8ZZPBA6mX0-VPY0hrHuKC5BA0Ly%20fyFSyp6h%20YbtILE0l4kXpebc3n8wXCu67e2%204CSe3peVKlVqiuaquiqD23PkBD205mQRAA):

```
interface Item {
  readonly description: string;
  readonly id: string;
}

interface MyInterface {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly propToReplace: number;
  readonly anotherPropToReplace: readonly Item[];
}

type ReplacedUser = ReplaceKeys<MyInterface, { propToReplace: 'total', anotherPropToReplace: 'items' }>;
```

In `ReplacedUser` I can see that the type is almost correct. The inferred type is:

```
{ id: string; total: number | readonly Item[]; items: number | readonly Item[]; }
```

... while I'm expecting:

```
{ id: string; total: number; items: readonly Item[]; }
```

---

What am I doing wrong? I'd like to know first how I can express that `P` needs to get the **values** passed in `U` to suppress Typescript errors and after that get the correct type for a specific `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to invert the `U` type parameter for your `ReplaceKeys`:

```
type PossibleKeys = number | string | symbol;
type ReplaceKeys<T extends {}, U extends Record<PossibleKeys, keyof T>> = Omit<T, ValueOf<U>> & {
    [K in keyof U]: T[U[K]]
};
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
type ReplacedUser = ReplaceKeys<MyInterface, { total: 'propToReplace', items: 'anotherPropToReplace' }>;
```

If though you cannot change the shape of the `U` thing become a bit trickier:

```
// Example types from your post
interface Item {
  readonly description: string;
  readonly id: string;
}

interface MyInterface {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly propToReplace: number;
  readonly anotherPropToReplace: readonly Item[];
}

// All possible key types
type PossibleKeys = number | string | symbol;

// Helper type to get all non-nullable values from type T
type DefinedValues<T> = NonNullable<T[keyof T]>;

// Helper type for your replacements object - a record whose values are valid keys
// and whose keys are also present in type T (the input type)
// 
// Partial is used to make sure you don't need to pass all keys of T in your replacements
type Replacements<T extends {}> = Partial<Record<keyof T, PossibleKeys>>;

// Helper type that swaps object keys for values
type Invert<T extends Replacements<C>, C extends {} = {}> = {
  [N in DefinedValues<T>]: {
    [K in keyof T]: N extends T[K] ? K : never
  }[keyof T]
}

type ReplacedKeys<T extends {}, R extends Replacements<T>> = Omit<T, keyof R | DefinedValues<R>> & {
  [N in keyof Invert<R>]: {
    [L in keyof R]: N extends R[L] ? (L extends keyof T ? T[L] : never) : never;
  }[keyof R]
}
```

Be aware thought that using the second approach does not warn you about having duplicate mappings:

```
type ReplacedUser = ReplacedKeys<MyInterface, { propToReplace: 'total', anotherPropToReplace: 'total' }>;
```

Check the [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFEA8EMFsAcA2BTUAXAnvZBnUAzAJwHtZQNiBXQ0eYnNAKAEsA7NZQ-aAY1QEkOZAN6NQoQsmgATYq0QZQ03D0LN4aZnIBcoBmtYBzANxiJU2fMXNpu-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-TMl2oBEiStYUsBdL0oMuhEeI-SHGR+4dvRoCkdBWF4GkzGDKAAD8oAsfkyDgYQZhODyawHgKgzOK4I45GOfDSJetKdtx874cemQYTBcEqQhk4MsuoAAPKwMwkFpMebGgPpdwUaS1Forgm7XqAABkOFmCRrGyfyYEQZ5HGMcRAAygV8o5HFcZhOmZP0kUCcJEbRdp2EOZ2wl8aloBiRJiaFRc4mlFJMmxZkCmjOMlJ2oa8FqRpeJPs1ZIaQAjHhHXqScNK+P4HCBHwx6LjeykKv1noAEy9cZLUDUNASeMg420C0WSLcgujVrUqKVqAS6mFNqmdScADMC3TRpg1+KtQQbdEoCVrWRr8NIR0na4+qsAw8rndIXW6H13WEVEtivV1lbHikxDpNtCq6F1x7VLUDSEM0COtDtuhDMdph-QD-ZA7NoM7TNODzecwiQ3tMPHg2aCoijaM1NGWNbR1+MCU4RNyCTlOXRTt1XRD72fQzsObTjSPnWzzoY003N48RfMimAYGovaYOOmdQRUwALDdQN3StI1rRtJJalorCs69zOHcdN5OmkDQEJQrC23ISiamOhCvnbjDKDwAeoPgXs+92pNBHdWmJdhi56QZPGOTtE5oJp14RoW8D-LodmgKqaqg4motmwNReZK79U64akfe5ovs8KiiBbMT4Kx2pADqNl1AAYlHzesD15zdxeJwRnTL2VozsuIzzoCo0rnPY4vasE0441OImAv-V3lN9-UQ9N3bNOA3HU8z1Dc8y-DG-I8v7PK1zctL1vG0P7jT-7SziDfT3owTul9e791PtHa648doaWnvTaG99VZPxXujNeSCFbq2Os9W+ksvrHSAU6bWjVPZnxbm3DugtD7TWPoPYedsTbQIVLAm+0s4boLyM-VemN14-wwZ-HCBBmDRwdn-Z2u9NagAavaXgfBmyMAntIGhECR5dQAHQ2FMAopRdC5BqO-vLIImij7gJ0aPVRqDuHsL4B8LRJjSGsFmuo6QRjqF2Ojo4p27x5HGJPqYxxFiVbvx2jYnxtD7GXVUbglxQNtHhNUfojq0TDaxMgeYjmligkKgkUQ6RPBZFbFsb4+xaipTECSWAop7j4lWOQOUskKSR4RI0YwIAA).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the such detailed explanation! The second approach is what I was looking for :).

Comment: Just for record, to remove the error in my type definition I should have used `NonNullable<ValueOf<U>>` (maybe more clear error messages could help :/), but of course, it doesn't solve the second problem, which is nicely solved above :)

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that with the second approach I can pass any value as key, not only the `keyof T`. Do you know how to fix this? Ex: `ReplaceKeys<MyInterface, { strangeKey: 'newKey', anotherPropToReplace: 'total' }>` should error in `strangeKey`, but it currently doesn't.

Comment: I updated the answer, switched the "direction" of type constrain around :) check it out

Comment: Nice, that works! I tested and it works, but for some reason, when I try to use it as a ReturnType of a function, it doesn't. Can you help me with this last part? I've placed this in this playground -> `bit.ly/2Ae5lj4` (I had to shorten it to fit here because playground generates a really long url).

Comment: I fixed the answer to get rid of that problem + updated the playground link with a working code, hope that helps!